# i am trying to incorporate the wireless communication in free rtos using arduino ide. any thoughts?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi, esp32, arduino-ide, freertos

it is told that core 0 is recommended be used for WIFI/BLE communication by default. if i do that and initialize wifi.begin() in void setup() then it is going to run on core 1(since setup task is running on core1). however, if i force wifi.begin() to be intialized in a task that is assigned to core 0, this causes ESP crash many times (if wifi is on core 1). i am trying to read 250 samples per second using hardware timer and to send that data through wireless communication using free rtos in arduino ide. i successfully collected the samples. but if i try to integrate the wifi communication, esp crash many time. any thoughts?
i referred  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F321087yYy4&list=PLEBQazB0HUyQ4hAPU1cJED6t3DU0h34bz&index=1 this material and there is no material for communication. need help.

Comment: The core used by WiFi driver is configured using ESP-IDF menuconfig: https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=9225

Comment: you use free rtos on top of rtos of the esp32 SDK?

Comment: Thank you Tarmo. i have developed my half of the project in arduino ide. in your provided link, they are saying it is possible if you use arduino-esp32 as an IDF component. Let me try it.